# What is the right way of using user defined functions inside a classes in web.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web.py

I want the user defined functions to be used inside the index class POST function .

I tried using self. someFunction() with no help. Can anyone tell me whats the right way of doing it

```
import web
class index():
    def GET(self):
        return 'hello'

    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        sendmail(self)

def sendmail(ind):
        web.config.smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        web.config.smtp_port = 587
        web.config.smtp_username = ''
        web.config.smtp_password = ''
        web.config.smtp_starttls = True
        web.sendmail('sender','receiver', 'subject ','message')

def main():
    ind = index()
    app = web.application(URLS, globals())
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output: A running web server at Port 8080, but sendmail() won't send any mail to the expected recipient

Comment: Please try to make your question more clear by also writing what exactly you're trying to achieve next time. Serge and me gave answers to two completely different questions, and I can't tell who of us got you right.

Comment: @Philip - I have updated my question, should i be more clear?

Comment: Yes. You should try to reduce your problem to a minimal, working example. That is either that accessing a page doesn't work or that sending mails doesn't. (Here, it is sending mails I presume..)

Comment: i want to send a mail. The index page prints an hello message.The problem is : I want to use the sendmail() function , i ant a clean way of using it.

Comment: @Philip- i get a data from A client application using POST(), after getting the data in data=web.data(). i want the parse the data received. where can i lay the functions like  parse_data():, sendmail(): in my function?

Comment: Did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

You can only call methods defined in the class with the syntax `self.method()` of `object.method()`.

If you need to call a simple function from a method and let it know about the object, you can do :

```
class index():

    def POST(self):
        # ...
        someFunction(self)

def someFunction(ind):
    'ind is an index object'
    #...
```

Comment: def main(): ind=index()   app = web.application(URLS, globals())
    app.run()  . But still am not able to use the user defined function.

Comment: -How can i use the user defined function to send a mail using inside the POST method

Comment: @Zumbaa : and what happens when you post to `index` ?

Comment: i get a data from A client application using POST(), after getting the data in data=web.data(). i want the parse the data received. where can i lay the functions like  parse_data():, sendmail(): in my function?

Comment: @Zumbaa: did you try it and what happened ? You can safely call functions from a method.

Comment: I have edited my code to what i want . I tried doing what you told, But it doesn't accesses the sendmail () function

Comment: @Zumbaa : Test element by element. Can you see if a function that only print some text is called. If it works, try to send a mail to a *local* debugging server. `python  -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer :25` will create a dummy server on localhost listening on port 25 that only locally displays messages. And only when all that works try to *actually* send mails.